# Is it possible to make compose compiler consider Flow's as Stable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

After creating report about composables/classes in my project, I've found out that my composables are not considered skippable by compose compiler. The reason for that is that I pass in constructor of my screen uiEvent which is of type Flow.

Is there any way that I can make Flow stable? I've read the documentation that flows aren't considered stable, but maybe someone found a workaround for that.

Here is part of my code:

```kotlin
@RootNavGraph(start = true)
@Destination
@Composable
fun CentralReturnsScreen(
    state: MutableStateFlow<CentralReturnsState>,
    onEvent: (CentralReturnsEvent) -> Unit,
    onNavigate: (Direction) -> Unit,
    uiEvent: Flow<UiEvent>,
    pagedList: LazyPagingItems<ClaimsAndReturnsList>,
    snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val centralReturnsState = state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    LaunchedEffect(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle) {
        lifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            uiEvent.collect { event ->
                when (event) {
                    is UiEvent.ShowSnackBar -> snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        message = event.message.asString(context = context)
                    )

                    else -> Unit
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wrapping it in a class marked `@Stable` should do the trick - see this: https://chrisbanes.me/posts/composable-metrics/#wrapper-class

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected!